# Drop rows that contain duplicate vlaues in two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains new_price and old_price columns I want to drop the rows that contains duplicated values in these two columns.

```
Product old_price   new_price
prod_name   44.05   44.05
prod_name   76.95   76.95
prod_name   2       -1
prod_name   34.95   -1
prod_name   45.95   45.95
prod_name   54.7    54.7
prod_name   29.95   29.95
prod_name   0       24.95
prod_name   1       41.1
prod_name   72.95   72.95
prod_name   32.95   32.95
prod_name   19.95   19.95
prod_name   43      43
prod_name   9       79
prod_name   40.5    40.5
prod_name   32      32
```

but the code returns wrong result some rows contain duplicate values.

```
price_log[price_log['old_price'] != price_log['new_price']]


Product old_price   new_price
prod_name   2       -1
prod_name   34.95   -1
prod_name   0       24.95
prod_name   1       41.1
prod_name   43      43
prod_name   9       79
prod_name   40.5    40.5
prod_name   32      32
```

the desired output is

```
Product old_price   new_price
prod_name   2       -1
prod_name   34.95   -1
prod_name   0       24.95
prod_name   1       41.1
prod_name   9       79
```

Comment: It works on my side. You should probably check if `40.5    40.5` are of the same type, e.g, `str` vs `float`.

Comment: Don't trust `==` to always return `True` for "equal" floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your entries to float:

```
price_log[price_log['old_price'].astype(float) != price_log['new_price'].astype(float)]
```

Comment: Why equality? OP wants to drop them.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the built-in [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Good point. But with `drop_duplicates()` you would also have the str-vs-float problem, right?

Comment: when he created the pandas df he should have set the dtype to float (assuming all his values were float), then it would have not been an issue in the first place.